# Change meta_value relating to specific meta_key

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a wordpress directory theme in which a bunch of listings are about to expire. The were all created on different days. I want to batch update the whole database so that all my listings are reset for another year as of today.

They related to the table wp_postmeta and the meta_key is "alive_days" and I need to update the pertaining meta_value.

If anyone can suggest an SQL query to fix this, I will be saved a from pulling out my hair.

Thanks in advance.

LLG

See http://snag.gy/KfJfB.jpg for screengrab of the database.

Comment: So you want to update _every single_ meta value with a key of `alive_days`?  What format do the values in the database at the moment take (your screen grab shows an empty value)?  Are they dates (if so, what format)>  Or integers (eg the number of days remaining)?

Comment: Some of them are empty for past posts that no longer exits. Posts that are still active show numbers of days e.g. "356" for one year. I know it's not necessary to update the unused posts, however I'm unsure how to differentiate between the two. thanks Hobo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your response to my question, this should do the trick (take a backup of your database first, just in case):

```
update wp_postmeta
   set meta_value = '365' -- I assume you meant that, not 356
 where meta_key = 'alive_days'
```

The existing blanks will be updated, but since they relate to posts that no longer exist, that shouldn't matter.  If you don't want to update them, you could add an extra condition (I assume they contain the empty string, not `null`, but the `ifnull` should handle that):

```
update wp_postmeta
   set meta_value = '365'
 where meta_key = 'alive_days'
   and ifnull(meta_value, '') != ''
```

Comment: Hobo - thank you, and in 0.0091 seconds my headache was gone :) I cosmically send you a big hug!

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to accept my answer (click the tick beside it) and/or upvote it.  It's how we show thanks around here :)